# monitor connected clients using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, monitoring

I am building a website with a node.js server.

How would i track logged-in users (clients) and store their id's on the node.js server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var http=require('http');

var connected_users={};

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.end('hi');
});

server.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.__fd=socket.fd;
    connected_users[socket.__fd]=socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log(connected_users);
    socket.on('close',function(){
        delete connected_users[socket.__fd];
        console.log(connected_users);
    }); 
});
server.listen(8080);
```

It prints out to console the array of connected users every time someone connects/disconnects

Answer (score 0):

You can use connect or express NPM modules (express is an extension of connect). Connect (and thus express) has support for cookie-based sessions. Express is a very lightweight and popular framework.

To store users persistently, you can use 'dirty' module. If you need a more advanced store - you can use MongoDB, Riak or even plain old SQL databases (postgreSQL and mySQL), however I suggest to start with dirty or riak to learn the modern approach (namely, key-value stores, in-memory databases, horizontal scalability, document-oriented and other noSQL databases).

Comment: The thing is i want to store a random id for a new connected client in an array and when they disconnect that this id wil be removed from that array.

Comment: HTTP is connectionless protocol. So you cannot track when a user disconnects. The code above is useless as most users will disconnect immediately after the connection.

Comment: Is there a way that this will be possible??

Answer (score 0):

If you use express then you should set a session middleware app.use(express.cookieParser()) and app.use(express.session({secret:'some secret'}). By default it stores in memory but you able to use database to store sessions. For more details look in [express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support).
Is it it?